# forEach loop in nested array of objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, key

Stucked right here! How can I iterate this array of objects saving the key of the dates (for example 10/06/2021)? and iterate the skills array of objects?

[image]

[image]

the array must see like:

```
    const data = [
  {
     name: 10/06/2021,
     sprint speed: "4.00",
     stamina: "4.00",
     acceleration: "4.00"
  },
    .....
    ....
    ...
  ]
```

I'm trying with:

```
Object.keys(element.dates).forEach((date) => {
        if (normalizedSkillsObject[date]) {
          let normalizedTemps = {
            ...normalizedSkillsObject[date],
            ...{ name: date, data: element.dates[date].skills },
          };
          normalizedSkillsObject = {...normalizedSkillsObject, [date]: normalizedTemps}
        } else {
          normalizedSkillsObject = {
            ...normalizedSkillsObject,
            [date]: { name: date, data: element.dates[date].skills.forEach(s => s.name) },
          };
        }
      });
```

But this is the output:

[image]

Comment: It would be easy to answer if you could add data array and expected output?

Comment: Do you only care about `sprint speed`, `stamina`, and `acceleration` in your output OR do you only want skills where the `avg` stat is NOT '0.00'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const json = [
  {
    dates: {
      "10/06/2021": {
        average: 4,
        skills: [
          { id: "1", name: "acceleration", avg: "4.00" },
          { id: "2", name: "sprint speed", avg: "4.00" },
          { id: "3", name: "stamina", avg: "4.00" },
        ],
      },
      "13/04/2021": {
        average: 2.97,
        skills: [
          { id: "1", name: "acceleration", avg: "4.00" },
          { id: "2", name: "sprint speed", avg: "4.00" },
          { id: "3", name: "stamina", avg: "4.00" },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    dates: {
      "20/04/2021": {
        average: 4,
        skills: [
          { id: "1", name: "acceleration", avg: "4.00" },
          { id: "2", name: "sprint speed", avg: "4.00" },
          { id: "3", name: "stamina", avg: "4.00" },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
];

const result = json.flatMap(({ dates }) => {
  return Object.entries(dates).map(([name, value]) =>
    Object.assign({ name }, ...value.skills.map(({ name, avg }) => ({ [name]: avg })))
  );
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = {
  dates: {
    "10/06/2021": {
      skills: [
        { id: 1, name: "accel", avg: "4.0" },
        { id: 2, name: "sprint speed", avg: "4.0" },
        { id: 2, name: "agility", avg: "0.00" },
      ],
    },
    "10/07/2021": {
      average: 4,
      skills: [
        { id: "1", name: "acceleration", avg: "4.00" },
        { id: "2", name: "sprint speed", avg: "4.00" },
        { id: "3", name: "stamina", avg: "4.00" },
      ],
    },
  },
};

const res = Object.entries(obj.dates).reduce(
  (acc, [date, { skills }]) => [
    ...acc,
    {
      name: date,
      ...skills
        .filter(({ avg }) => Number(avg)) // remove skill avg's that are 0
        .reduce((a, { name, avg }) => ({ ...a, [name]: avg }), {}),
    },
  ],
  []
);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a way to test this - you didn't give data to work with, but it looks pretty straight forward. Post your data if this isn't right and I'll fine tune

```
let data = {}
for (const [date, props] of Object.entries(element.dates)) {
  let tmpObj= {name: date};
  props.skills
     .filter( skill => ["sprint speed","stamina","acceleration"].contains(skill.name))
     .forEach(sk => {tmpObj[sk.name] = sk.avg});
  data.push(tmpObj);
}

console.log(data)
```

Comment: I don't believe there is supposed to be any filtering applied

Comment: It's only filtering the skills array to get the skills the OP requested in their expected output `the array must see like:`...

Comment: I think I see what you mean. OP was not very clear and I figured they didn't want to type the rest out. Maybe they don't want results that are 0...?

Comment: Yep. Well at any rate, OP has a few nearly identical solutions to choose from... :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
const obj = {
  dates: {
    "10/06/2021": {
      skills: [
        { id: 1, name: "accel", avg: "4.0" },
        { id: 2, name: "sprint speed", avg: "4.0" },
        { id: 2, name: "agility", avg: "0.00" },
      ],
    },
    "10/07/2021": {
      average: 4,
      skills: [
        { id: "1", name: "acceleration", avg: "4.00" },
        { id: "2", name: "sprint speed", avg: "4.00" },
        { id: "3", name: "stamina", avg: "4.00" },
      ],
    },
  },
};

const res = Object.entries(obj.dates).reduce(
  (acc, [date, { skills }]) => [
    ...acc,
    {
      name: date,
      ...skills
        .filter(({ avg }) => Number(avg)) // remove skill avg's that are 0
        .reduce((a, { name, avg }) => ({ ...a, [name]: avg }), {}),
    },
  ],
  []
);
console.log(res);
```

```js
const obj = {
  dates: {
    "10/06/2021": {
      skills: [
        { id: 1, name: "accel", avg: "4.0" },
        { id: 2, name: "sprint speed", avg: "4.0" },
        { id: 2, name: "agility", avg: "0.00" },
      ],
    },
    "10/07/2021": {
      average: 4,
      skills: [
        { id: "1", name: "acceleration", avg: "4.00" },
        { id: "2", name: "sprint speed", avg: "4.00" },
        { id: "3", name: "stamina", avg: "4.00" },
      ],
    },
  },
};

const res = Object.entries(obj.dates).reduce(
  (acc, [date, { skills }]) => [
    ...acc,
    {
      name: date,
      ...skills
        .filter(({ avg }) => Number(avg)) // remove skill avg's that are 0
        .reduce((a, { name, avg }) => ({ ...a, [name]: avg }), {}),
    },
  ],
  []
);
console.log(res);
```